# /dev/nvme0n1p2: [ 4.772818] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, bluetooth, tty, nvme

Goal: Boot to GUI Login.

Had warnings of disk being almost full. Deleted some conda venvs and docker images. Crashed immediately upon executing run of docker image.

Error at Bootup:

```
[   0.453097] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.MHBR],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[   0.453140] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PTID.PBAR],
AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dsfield-500)
[.   1.037563] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling inst
ead
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 8607152/61022208 files, 236685514/244059136 blocks
[   0.453097] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_N
OT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[   4.070446] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[   4.772818] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

Up until then, I would see the first 4 lines and machine would still boot to GUI login.

Thankfully, I can login to bash via. TTY using `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2`, and see all my files there.

`df -h`

```
Filesystem       Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            3.2G 2.3M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   916G 887G     0 100% /
tmpfs             16G    0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5.0M 4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock  
/dev/nvme0n1p1   511M 6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
temps            3.2G  88K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

`sudo apt update` ran successfully

`sudo apt upgrade` : `E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Error persists after:

- `sudo apt clean`
- `sudo apt autoremove`
- `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*`
- `sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/*`

After deleting certain folders, I won't miss at my peril, I can now `sudo apt upgrade`

Now stuck on `Failed to start Record successful boot for GRUB`

Comment: Delete some unimportant files in your or any other user's home directory ... Or move some to an external disk/USB stick ... A few Gigs would suffice ... And no GRAS way around that I'm afraid.

Comment: I figured I had to, haha. Thanks for commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Launch TTY using `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F2`
2. `df -h ~` and detect which drive partition is `Use%` `100%` (in my case `/dev/nvme0n1p2`)
3. Enter `/dev/nvme0n1p2` by `cd ~`
4. Delete what you're comfortable with, until `Use%` `99%`
5. `startx`

Answer (score 0):

- Restart your computer and repeatedly press the Shift key (or Esc key on some systems) during boot to access the GRUB menu. From there, choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" or a similar option that includes recovery mode.
- Select the kernel version you're currently using (or the latest one available) followed by the "Recovery Mode" option. This will boot Ubuntu into a minimal environment with various recovery options.
- In recovery mode, you might find an option like "Clean" or "Free Disk Space." This option might clear temporary files or perform other cleanup tasks to free up space on your disk.
- If there's no specific "Free Disk Space" option, you can access a terminal in recovery mode and use commands like "apt clean" or "apt autoremove" to remove cached packages and unused dependencies, freeing up some space.