# ubuntu not booting due to malformed MSFT vendor event

Tags: boot, bluetooth, gui

When attempting to boot ubuntu, I get the error message Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02. Ctrl+alt+f3 works but I am unable to boot to the gui. Ubuntu is the only os on this device.

Comment: Please provide details as to what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, you're asking about & have on your device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/dev/nvme0n1p2: \[ 4.772818\] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473836/dev-nvme0n1p2-4-772818-bluetooth-hci0-malformed-msft-vendor-event-0x02)

Comment: I really wish you came back and posted what the answer was. I'm suddenly having this problem.